# How to know if a variable had a different mapping in a different time set

Tags: sql, hql

My question focuses on finding out if a variable was mapped differently in a previous time period.

I want to see if last month the place names could have switched (Example: Kansas was coming in for FLP instead of RLT).

I currently have three variables coming in as below in table location_info

| area_name | place_name | set_report_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RLT | Kansas | 2023-03 |
| RLT | Seattle | 2023-03 |
| FLP | Orlando | 2023-03 |
| FLP | Tulsa | 2023-03 |

I know that area_name = RLT can only be Kansas/Seattle and area_name = FLP can only be Orlando/Tulsa.

I want to build a query which can show me the differences between how they were mapped last month to this month using above three variables. I was thinking I can build a sub-select query?

```
SELECT area_name, place_name, set_report_date
FROM location_info
where set_report_date in ('2023-03','2023-04')
       (select distinct area_name 
        FROM location_info);
```

I was thinking I can build a sub-select query?

```
SELECT distinct place_name, area_name, set_report_date
FROM location_info
WHERE place_name IN
        (SELECT place_name
         FROM location_info
         WHERE area_name IN ('RLT',FLP')
         AND set_report_date in ('2023-03','2023-04'));
```

This ended up giving me all the reporting dates starting from January and all other existing area_names

Then I tried this and it got closer to my expected result but still I feel like I am going about this wrong

```
SELECT distinct place_name, area_name, set_report_date
FROM location_info
WHERE area_name IN ('RLT',FLP')
AND set_report_date in ('2023-03','2023-04');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `not exists`

```
select area_name, place_name, set_report_date
from location_info
where not exists (
select area_name, place_name, set_report_date
from location_info
where (area_name = 'RLT' and place_name = 'Kansas' or place_name = 
'Seattle')
or (area_name = 'FLP' and place_name = 'Orlando' or place_name = 'Tulsa');
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare the mapping differences between last month and this month for the variables area_name and place_name, you can use a self-join approach. Here's an example query that should give you the desired result:

```
SELECT
  a.set_report_date AS last_month,
  a.area_name AS last_month_area_name,
  a.place_name AS last_month_place_name,
  b.set_report_date AS this_month,
  b.area_name AS this_month_area_name,
  b.place_name AS this_month_place_name
FROM
  location_info a
JOIN
  location_info b
ON
  a.place_name = b.place_name
WHERE
  a.set_report_date = '2023-03' AND
  b.set_report_date = '2023-04' AND
  a.area_name <> b.area_name;
```

This query will give you a result set with the columns last_month, last_month_area_name, last_month_place_name, this_month, this_month_area_name, and this_month_place_name. Each row in the result represents a mapping difference between last month and this month. It only includes rows where the area_name is different between the two months.

Make sure to adjust the dates in the WHERE clause (a.set_report_date and b.set_report_date) to match the desired time period you want to compare.

Note that the query assumes that there are no duplicates in the location_info table for the same combination of place_name and set_report_date. If duplicates exist, you may need to modify the query accordingly to suit your specific data structure.